# Running C++ Jupiter Notebook in VSCode Insiders

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, xeus-cling

I have installed **xeus**, **xeus-cling** and **jupyter extension**. I changed the kernel to one of the C++ versions, the cell language to C++ but when I click run the cell never outputs. Can someone please help me solve this?

Comment: do you use the conda environment ?

Comment: yes. Also, I am on a macOS

Comment: it works perfectly on jupyter notebook/lab but i didn't try it on vscode. will check it on afternoon on vscode.

Comment: I can agree, it works on jupyter notebook for me as well, the issue is with vscode though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Running xeus-cling under vs-code

[image]

Ceus works in the vs-code environment. You have to activate your conda environment and invoke vs-code from it (i use the code insiders edition). In linux this looks like

```
conda activate xeus-cling # my env for xeus-cling; where i compiled cling
```

then invoke code (insiders) in your project directory

```
code-insiders .& # or code .& if you are using the stable version
```

If you have still problems try the following:

- start a jupyter notebook from command line (of course in your conda environment described above)

  ```
   jupyter notebook --no-browser
  ```

  Copy or remember the line with the token, which looks like `http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=8daf8f57bef55918defb467defc55f0305803caa27dd01d2`
- next go to code-insiders and click on the bottom bar **Jupyter Server: Remote** [image]
- on the top of the window a list will pop up, looking like

[image]

- select **Existing** or copy the token into it
- now a message should appear **reload kernel** , click on the button to do so
- in the bottom bar select the kernel to e.g. C++14
- create a new blank jupyter worksheet and don't forget to change the cell to C++ !!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It indeed seems to work, I am probably doing something wrong. Trying to replicate your steps, when I run a cell I always get a notification with "Connecting to kernel:C++14"  which immediately changes to "Canceled". Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: Thanks, it works now! As I understand, the problem is that vscode does not properly start or connect to the local notebook server?

Comment: yes, seem so. however, i prefer to start the notebook this way as i have full control over extensions, ...

Answer (score 4):

Heres a solution without having to activate the conda environment. The following commands are what worked on ubuntu:focal

Update conda:

```
conda update conda --yes
```

Create the environment to install xeus-cling kernel:

```
conda create -n xeus-cling --yes
```

Install xeus-cling kernel in the xeus-cling environment created earlier:

```
conda install xeus-cling -c conda-forge -n xeus-cling --yes
```

Find where your conda environments are installed by looking for `envs directories` in the output of the following command:

```
conda info
```

My conda environments were located in `/etc/miniconda/envs`. Thus there will be a subdirectory for each environment which holds all the installed packages. The kernels are located in `xeus-cling/share/jupyter/kernels`. The path starts with `xeus-cling` because that's what we named the conda environment earlier.

Inside of the `kernels/` directory you will find a few c++ kernels. To install the conda xeus-cling kernel directly into Jupyter do the following:

```
jupyter kernelspec install /etc/miniconda/envs/xeus-cling/share/jupyter/kernels/xcpp11 --sys-prefix
jupyter kernelspec install /etc/miniconda/envs/xeus-cling/share/jupyter/kernels/xcpp14 --sys-prefix
jupyter kernelspec install /etc/miniconda/envs/xeus-cling/share/jupyter/kernels/xcpp17 --sys-prefix
```

Open VS Code as you normally would. No need to activate the conda environment. Create a new Jupyter Notebook. Finally, make sure you select the C++ Kernel in the upper right corner of the screen.

[image: VS Code select kernel]

I used @abu_bua answer above and these [docs from the xeus-cling project](https://xeus-cling.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-the-kernel-spec) to figure this out. I hope this helps.

Happy coding!

Comment: How can you change the cell language mode to c++ in vscode? In my jupyter notebook there seems to be no option for cpp

Comment: The code cell language will change by selecting the kernel in the upper right corner.